# Get the value of dropdown menu which is clicked in a webpage

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am trying to get the value of dropdown menu which is clicked in a page. Here is what I am doing now :

```
<c:forEach items="${menuItem.dropdown}" var="dItem">
    <li>
        <a href="${dropdownItem.link}" onclick="<c:set var="clickedDropdown" value="${dItem.name}"/>">${dItem.name}</a>
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

But when I clicked on the dropdown menu, it sets the the value of last dropdown menuitem. I am not getting correct value. Is there any way, I can get that dropdown menu item value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `onclick="<c:set var="clickedDropdown" value="${dItem.name}"/>"`

Although `<c:set var="clickedDropdown" value="${dItem.name}"/>` is inside `onclick`, it will execute beforehand when the `jsp` compiles. And as it is inside `foreach`, naturally the last value remains as the value of the variable.

Even if you want to set the variable using `javascript`, you cannot, because `javascript` works in frontend and `jstl` works in backend.

So, apparently there is actually no way to achieve this. You need to change your approach completely.

Comment: @AmitKumar: Yes, that can be a solution. You might use data attribute to store values and then jquery to retrieve and send ajax request. Although cannot tell more without seeing more code.